# Is there a plugin that provides a stackoverflow style editor for wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, editor

I am tired of the tinymce editor in wordpress and I really love the stackoverflow editor which allows me to write with markdown grammar. So I want to write blog with markdown in wordpress.

Now I am using this plugin in my wordpress:

> Plugin Name: Markdown QuickTags
>   Plugin URI: http://brettterpstra.com/code/markdown-quicktags
>   Description: Replaces the WordPress QuickTags with Markdown-compatible ones
>   Version: 0.8.2
>   Author: Brett Terpstra
>   Author URI: http://brettterpstra.com
>   License: GPLv2

It replaces the original editor of wordpress and provides a light-weight interface for me to write with markdown. However, compared with Stackoverflow's editor, it lacks:

1. The SO editor have auto syntax highlighting. I don't need to specify which kind of language I am typing in. The Markdown QuickTags plugin do not provide the ability for syntax highlighting, and plugins like [Wp-markdown-syntax-highlight](https://github.com/boblu/wp-markdown-syntax-highlight) requires me to manually add a tag to indicate the type of language. Also, I have no idea if the two plugins could work together.
2. The SO editor provides live preview, which is the most cool part of SO.

Is there any wordpress plugin(s), or combination of plugins that can meet my requirement? I personally could do some development but I know little about php and js, so it's really hard for me to write one from scratch (or from the two plugins I mentioned above).

**Point 1 above is the most important.** And I **don't care** if the plugin auto-converts markdown to html, or requires me to click a button like "render" before publishing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Welcome to WordPress stack exchange! Just yesterday I created [WP-Markdown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-markdown/), which enables Markdown on your posts.

It also provides the same interface as this website (the toolbar, and live preview) - however, currently only for comments and bbPress forums (if enabled). That said, (since it would be straightforward to do), I am planning on adding an option to enable a 'back-end' live preview. Hope that helps.

**Edit:** Since 1.1 this now includes an option to enable the toolbar and preview for the post editor, and so now actually does what the OP asked for :D.

Comment: I am using WP-Markdown now. It's really good. I look forward to the stackoverflow style interface for wp back-end. One thing to ask: how does the article with markdown stored in the db? Is it rendered to HTML when showing the post, or on saving the post?

Comment: It's saved to db as HTML so you can deactivate without any problems.

Comment: Nice! And I can always see markdown code in the editor when I want to edit the post. So it does some conversion from HTML to Markdown when I edit? Also here is my test with the plugin: http://dante.im/test-markdown-2/ It works well with WP's Twenty-Eleven.

Comment: @coolcfan See updated answer

Comment: Thanks for this great plugin. However, I don't understand why it doesn't highlight code on the index page? It works just fine on posts pages after configuration ... is there a way to add a filter for this? I'm a Wordpress newbie, help would be appreciated :) Here's my website : http://aarails.com

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto glad you like it. Please post plug-in specific questions on the [plug-in's GitHub page](https://github.com/stephenh1988/WP-Markdown) :)

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto Change the return line of `function loadPrettify()` to `return is_singular($savedtypes) || is_home();` may be one solution. The function is in WP-Markdown.php. Don't know the line number cuz' I edited it in WP's admin page.