# How can I implement a simple post editor?

Tags: post-editor

I want a simple post editor for WordPress, it should be something like [tumblr editor](http://www.tumblr.com/new/text) or the stackoverflow editor.

My questions:

1. Is there any plugin I can use? (I just can't find it)
2. If no plugin, how can I implement it? Is there any example?

(I saw one site has such editor using WordPress, but they have reworked their site now)

Comment: What's wrong with the default visual editor?

Comment: It is just too complicated for my case, I want a simpler one,like the tumblr editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Stackexchange Editor with the [WP-Markdown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-markdown/) Plugin, created by Steve Harris in this [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/is-there-a-plugin-that-provides-a-stackoverflow-style-editor-for-wordpress).